# Moving to a DLL

Tags: c#, dll

I've been tasked with moving the more useful parts of my code into a dll (if possible) for ip protection and to stop other developers changing parts that don't need to be changed.. I'm curious on how best to handle the namespaces and method parameters that relate to classes that I have created..

Is it just as simple as making sure they are in the same namespace? I get the feeling this will cause problems for others when the dll is to be used in other applications..

The only other viable solution I can see coming forward is to move my class variables into this new dll and then use them under this namespace..

If its needed im using winforms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how moving the code to a dll will protect your IP better.

That being said, my suggestion is just to copy the code to minimize the amount of the client code which needs to be rewritten. You will more likely need to change some classes from `internal` to `public`, or at least some methods visibility.

There is no reason that keeping the same namespaces will cause troubles for using the dll in other apps if your namespaces are even moderately sensible. In worst case, you can alias the namespaces/class names (with `using` directive) in the client apps to solve the issues if there are any.

Comment: Its still an early stage of development and working closely with some developers outside of the company so I don't want to show all the code if i can avoid it, I think you are right though and moving the code seems to be the way forward :)

Comment: well, they will have the access to your dll, so they can easily disassemble it (e.g. with Reflector, DotPeek or some other tools), so unless you use some good obfuscator, it won't help much.

Comment: well, it is indeed, but they are 3 mouse clicks from the source code :) actually, the community (free) version of DotFuscator is good enough for this purpose, but it will likely break at least some code which relies on reflection.